# Levinson algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy

I need to determine if a lot of different Toeplitz matrices are singular. I would like to be able to count exactly how many 12 by 12 0-1 Toeplitz matrices are singular for example. Here is some code that does this.

```
import itertools
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np

n = 12
singcount = 0
for longtuple in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = 2*n-1):
    A = toeplitz(longtuple[0:n], longtuple[n-1:2*n-1])
    if (np.isclose(scipy.linalg.det(A),0)):
        singcount +=1
print singcount
```

However `scipy.linalg.det` is a very inefficient way to do this. In principle [Levinson Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson_recursion) is faster but I cannot see how to implement it.   Can anyone get me started (or is there an even faster and better way)?

Comment: If your matrices are that small, the difference between Levinson and `det` is likely not very big. LU is ~ 2n^3/3 flops, Levinson ~3n^2 or so. Most of the cost will come from operation overheads in Python. You may want to use `numpy.linalg.det` which is a little bit faster.

Comment: Levinson's algorithm blows up if any leading principal minor of your matrix is singular.  You don't want to use it for this.

Comment: @tmyklebu Oh! Thank you. Is there a more suitable algorithm?

Comment: I'd just use `det` for this.  But you could play around with Berlekamp-Massey over a sufficiently large finite field---say GF(50021).  There's a vast literature on Toeplitz systems.  I'm not particularly familiar with it, but I think the standard reference is Kailath's "Linear systems."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to speedup `toeplitz` and `det` calls:

- work in `2**k` batch size
- create a `toeplitz` index first
- in NumPy 1.8, `det` is a general ufunc, which can calculate may det in one call.

Code:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz, det
```

Here is the original code:

```
%%time
n = 12
todo = itertools.islice(itertools.product([0,1], repeat = 2*n-1), 0, 2**16)
r1 = []
for longtuple in todo:
    A = toeplitz(longtuple[0:n], longtuple[n-1:2*n-1])
    r1.append(det(A))
```

Here is the optimized code:

```
%%time
batch = 2**10
todo = itertools.islice(itertools.product([0,1], repeat = 2*n-1), 0, 2**16)
idx = toeplitz(range(n), range(n-1, 2*n-1))

r2 = []
while True:
    rows = list(itertools.islice(todo, 0, batch))
    if not rows:
        break
    rows_arr = np.array(rows)
    A = rows_arr[:, idx]
    r2.extend(np.linalg.det(A).tolist())
```

Here is the time result:

```
original: Wall time: 4.65 s
optimized: Wall time: 646 ms
```

We the check the result:

```
np.allclose(r1, r2)
```

You can increase the speed by `unpackbits()`:

```
%%time
r3 = []
todo = np.arange(0, 2**16).astype(np.uint32).byteswap().view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, 4)
for i in range(todo.shape[0]//batch):
    B = np.unpackbits(todo[i*batch:(i+1)*batch], axis=-1)
    rows_arr = B[:, -23:]
    A = rows_arr[:, idx]
    r3.extend(np.linalg.det(A).tolist())
```

the time is:

```
Wall time: 494 ms
```

Here is the full code for the singcount for n=10:

```
%%time
count = 0
batch = 2**10
n = 10
n2 = 10*2-1
idx = toeplitz(range(n), range(n-1, 2*n-1))
todo = np.arange(0, 2**n2).astype(np.uint32).byteswap().view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, 4)
for i in range(todo.shape[0]//batch):
    B = np.unpackbits(todo[i*batch:(i+1)*batch], axis=-1)
    rows_arr = B[:, -n2:]
    A = rows_arr[:, idx]
    det = np.linalg.det(A)
    count += np.sum(np.isclose(det, 0))
print count
```

The output is 43892, and it took 2.15s on me PC.

Comment: How do you get the equivalent of singcount? For n = 10 the answer should be 43892 I believe (I also fixed my code).

Comment: I get a speed up about a factor of 30! Why is it so much faster?